# Neo4j HA (embedded) via Spring?

Tags: spring, neo4j, high-availability

Using 1.8.2 -- trying to set up (initially) a 2-node HA cluster.

Following section "22.5.4. Start Neo4j Embedded in HA mode" of

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html

I have added the following to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-ha</artifactId>
   <version>${neo4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and modified my application-content.xml to the following:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

<context:property-placeholder 
        location="file:/etc/whiteRabbit.properties" />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase"
                destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="${database.path}" />
                <constructor-arg index="1"> 
                        <map>
                                <entry key="ha.server_id" value="${server.id}"></entry>
                                <entry key="ha.server" value="${ha.server.address}:${ha.server.port}"></entry>
                                <entry key="ha.coordinators" value="${coordinators}"></entry>
                                <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="port=1331"></entry>
                                <entry key="ha.pull_interval" value="1"></entry>
                        </map>
                </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

/etc/whiteRabbit.properties contains:

node 1 (address: 192.168.1.68)

```
server.id=1
ha.server.address=localhost
ha.server.port=6001
database.path=/databases/data/graph.db
coordinators=localhost:2181,192.168.1.100:2181
```

and node 2 (address 192.168.1.100)

```
server.id=2
ha.server.address=localhost
ha.server.port=6001
database.path=/databases/data/graph.db
coordinators=localhost:2181,192.168.1.68:2181
```

When I start up each instance, I get the normal startup logs, then

```
14:57:58.171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  neo4j - WARNING! Deprecated configuration options used. See manual for details

14:57:58.171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  neo4j - neo4j.ext.udc.disable has been replaced with neo4j.ext.udc.enabled

14:57:58.171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  neo4j - cannot configure writers and searchers individually since they go together
```

(only the first two of those sem to relate to the change to HA)

then.. nothing.... (!)

Startup simply stops there. Given that the setup configuration for standalone servers in the page noted above mentions starting the coordinator instances as a separate part fo the process, is that something I need to do manually here? Or should that just take care of itself? How do I find logging info to start working out why I'm just seeing the nodes hang? BTW behaviour is no different if I start up just a single node -- same hang, same place in the logs...

Im guessing I'm missing something simple?

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your bean pull in your properties file. Also to do HA, you use the Class `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase`. Do something like this:

```
<bean id="configuration" class="org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil" factory-method="load">
    <constructor-arg value="/etc/whiteRabbit.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg name="storeDir" index="0" value="${database.path}" />
    <constructor-arg name="config" index="1" ref="configuration" />
</bean>
```

However the `configuration` bean should point to a `neo4j.properties` file, which you can have contain all the properties you have above.

Comment: You say "to do HA, you use the Class HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseService" -- but your example uses org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase? What am I missing? Thanks for the tip on the config file: makes life easier, but my instance still hangs at the same place ;-(

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong name, I'll fix it. Do you have your coordinator up and running? You need to start those separately, which is usually a separate executable named `Neo4jCoordinator`. Did you follow the guide http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html?

Comment: Coordinators -- that was part of my original question -- that documentation doesn't IMHO make clear if you still need to start those manually if running embedded -- seems you do need to? Does that work any differently when using an embedded DB? Seems a little odd as that will also start up (separate) neo4j server instances, yes? Do the config files for those need to point to the actual location of the embdedded DB?

Comment: You need to start up the separate coordinator in `Neo4j` as they are separate entities. They are running Zookeeper and are supposed to be stand-alone instances so that they do not go down if the DB does. When you are using an `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` you don't need the coordinator, but to use `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase` you need to have the coordinator started up prior to starting it up, even if you are running from Java code.

Comment: @DarrellBerry can you plz explain me, i am still not getting it.Do i need separate neo4j servers running for each cluster?? If yes,where will be the data,it is only in directory of application or will automatically copied to all servers.