# Runs multiple web application with same embedded neo4j db

Tags: neo4j

It is required to run multiple application on same `neo4j` db. But when I try to do that, I am meeting a problem about locking.

Neo4j is locking itself when an application is using it. Multiple application can't be run.

The exception is like,

```
Unable to lock store [/opt/neo4j-lojika-db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store
```

Is there a way to run multiple web application with same `embedded neo4j` db.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this way. You have two options

1. Use [Neo4j HA](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-how.html) or
2. Run Neo4j in server mode rather than embedded mode. If your application is simple then you can use the REST api provided by Neo4j out of box. If your service layer is more involved then, put a service layer on top of a single Neo4j embedded instance and let each application talk to Neo4j through this service layer.

Comment: Actually I am using `spring-data-neo4j`. Is there a way to integrate `spring-data-neo4j` with [Neo4j HA](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-how.html)

Comment: @AhmetDAL You can get started from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524542/neo4j-ha-embedded-via-spring